# change select tags by choosing first and check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox

I have dynamic number of select tag and a checkbox all i need is a simple  javascript code 
when i change the first select tag and check the checkbox all other selected will change to the same as the first tag

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck">
<select id="first">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="third">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="fourth">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

when i change the first select and check the checkbox the other select changes to the same as first select 
thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you want the action to occur when the checkbox is checked or when the selection is made in the first select? Or when a selection is made in the first select, and the checkbox is checked then set the value of the other selects?

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or do you need native javascript?

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/rominux/Lh33woeo/3/`

Comment: i need the action after checking the check box to change the other select like the first select

Comment: Rome : i tried your code but it's not working please check it and tell me

Comment: Rome : i need to first change the select >> second check the checkbox then the changes occurs to the other select tags

Comment: @Ouda are you facing difficulty in running the snippet in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guss user wants to -> First change first select box and then check checkbox to change rest select boxes

```js
function updateSel(obj){
if(obj.checked==true){ // change only when it is checked
var selElems=document.getElementById('selectorDiv').getElementsByTagName('select') /*applies to all select elements inside div with id 'selectorDiv'*/
var val;
for(var i=0;i<selElems.length;i++){
    if(i==0)(
     val=selElems[i].value
    )
    selElems[i].value=val
}
}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" onchange="updateSel(this)">
<div id="selectorDiv">
<select id="first">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="third">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<select id="fourth">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much ... your code is working perfectly but i have an issue.. i have other selects in my page so the code changes all select tags in my page

Comment: @Ouda  I have added a wrapper div containing all select tags . Now this action is limited with in this wrapper.Check updated answer